# MvC DropDownList with connection to DB

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have this dropdown that populates itself with values from DB, but somehow is null when it gets to the view.

This is my Model

```
public class ListProblem
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
        List<ListProblem> ProblemList = new List<ListProblem>();
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public int ID { get; set; }

        ListProblem p = null;
        public List<ListProblem> GetProblems()
        {
            conn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=IBWS05\\MSSQLSERVER2012;Initial Catalog=Houston;Integrated Security=True";
            conn.Open();
            using (conn)
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select Title from Problems");
                cmd.Connection = conn;
                SqlDataReader rd = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (rd.Read())
                {
                    p = new ListProblem();
                    p.Title = rd["Title"].ToString();
                    ProblemList.Add(p);

                }

            }
            return ProblemList;
        }
    }
```

And this is my Controller

```
    public ActionResult Index()
            {
                GetProblems();
                return View("~/Views/OurFolder.cshtml");
            }
public ActionResult GetProblems()
        {
            ListProblem list = new ListProblem();
            List<ListProblem> l = new List<ListProblem>();
            l = list.GetProblems();
            ViewData["Problem"] = l;


                return View("~/Views/OurFolder.cshtml", list);
        }
```

And in my View

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model=>model.Id,new `SelectList(Model.Title,"ID","Title","Select option"))`
```

Can someone please tell me, what I do wrong and how to solve this?

Comment: You are giving the View a list of `ListProblem`, but it does not look like that is your model Type in the view (but you haven't shown that). And, FWIW, that is not a model, you should not have your model doing all that logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set the list using `ViewData` then you should use:

```
@Html.DropDownList("SelectedProblem", 
new SelectList((IEnumerable) ViewData["Problem"], "ID", "Title"))
```

The first parameter `SelectedProblem` is used when you post back your data to the server.